# acceptConnectionFromPeer generates EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, bluetooth

I try to setup a bluetooth connection between 2 devices (iPhone, iPad..).

Everyting works fine until the client makes a connection request and the host crashes when calling acceptConnectionFromPeer (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

```
-(void)session:(GKSession*)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString*)peerID
{
  NSError* error=nil;
  [m_pSession acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error];
}
```

`m_pSession` is valid.. trying to use

```
 NSString* displayName = [m_pSession displayNameForPeer:peerID];
```

in the same place works fine

If anyone has an ideea what's wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `session` that is getting notified of the connection request isn't the same session that referenced by `m_pSession`. Trying changing to:

```
-(void)session:(GKSession*)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString*)peerID
{
  NSError* error=nil;
  [session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error];
}
```